# Wordpress query_posts order by date when excluding a category

Tags: wordpress

I want to exclude a category and order the results by date with query_posts while preserving existing query parameters and order the results by date.

According to the Wordpress documentation I should add (or over-ride) parameters in the following way:

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=date&order=ASC&cat=-1' );
```

The results are right but ordering them by date doesn't work (ASC and DESC).

Only ordering the results works fine:

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=date&order=ASC' );
```

Only excluding a category, without ordering the results, works fine:

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&cat=-1 );
```

Also including certain categories and ordering the results works fine:

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=date&order=ASC&cat=2' );
```

Of course I can work around it by building an array of the right categories first, then use these categories in the query_posts. Something like the following:

```
$include = array();

$categories = get_categories( array('exclude' => 1) );

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $include[] = $category->term_id;
}
```

But I can't figure out why the combination of excluding a category and ordering by date doesn't work when using query_posts.

Tested with versions 3.9.1 and 4.0.1 of Wordpress. Both giving same results.

Is this a bug in Wordpress or is it something in my code?

EDIT:

Tested WP_Query and pre_get_posts based on comments but both returning same results as query_posts.

**WP_Query example**

```
$args = array(
    'category__not_in'  => array(1),
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**pre_get_posts example**

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Everything works fine until a category is excluded.

Comment: `query_posts` is problematic and not the recommended way to alter a query (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Use `pre_get_posts` instead.

Comment: Getting same results with pre_get_posts. Only ordering or only excluding a category works fine, but when using a combination of both, the ordering doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I think the problem is caused by the generated SQL query (which is the same using query_posts or WP_Query or pre_get_posts).

When ordering by date and excluding a category with the following code:

```
query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=date&order=ASC&cat=-1' );
```

The following query is executed:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (1) ) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

In this case the ORDER BY doesn't work in combination with GROUP BY. You can find more info on this in other questions on Stackoverflow. For example: [Using ORDER BY and GROUP BY together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030787/using-order-by-and-group-by-together)

I think the best workaround is to first build an array of categories which needs to be included. Then use this array in query_posts:

```
$include = array();

// Get all categories except category_id 1 (or other).
$categories = get_categories( array('exclude' => 1) ); 

// Loop categories to build array with category id's
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $include[] = $category->term_id;
}

// Query posts: order by date and only include categories from array
query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=date&order=ASC&cat=' . implode(',',$include) );
```

The generated query will be (2 and 3 are the included category id's):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2,3) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

In this case the ordering by date will be working fine because of the different query buildup (using INNER JOIN).

Answer (score 0):

You should try declaring a [new WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of using `query_posts()`.

Comment: No luck. WP_Query giving same result as query_posts and pre_get_posts. Ordering by date doesn't work when excluding a category.