# Filter for most recent client version in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a database and I have used select/join statements to try to create a leaderboard based on the number of games users of an app have played, along with information on their device.

My issue is that the database contains multiple rows for one user if they have downloaded multiple release versions of the app. My table looks something like:

```
+--------+---------+----------+-------------+
|# games | user id | platform | app version |
+--------+---------+----------+-------------+
|   15   |   1     |     ios  |   3.2.1     |
+--------+---------+----------+-------------+
|   13   |   2     | android  |   2.0.3     |
+--------+---------+----------+-------------+
|   13   |   2     | android  |   3.2.1     |
+--------+---------+----------+-------------+
|   13   |   2     | android  |   3.1.0     |
+--------+---------+----------+-------------+
|   11   |   3     |     ios  |   3.1.5     |
+--------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

Is there a way to consolidate each unique user id with multiple rows (from having used multiple versions) into one row, which only contains info on the most recent version? That is, the above table would be consolidated to this :

```
+--------+---------+----------+-------------+
|# games | user id | platform | app version |
+--------+---------+----------+-------------+
|   15   |   1     |     ios  |   3.2.1     |
+--------+---------+----------+-------------+
|   13   |   2     | android  |   3.2.1     |
+--------+---------+----------+-------------+
|   11   |   3     |     ios  |   3.1.5     |
+--------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Does the answer to this do the job for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030787/using-order-by-and-group-by-together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all details from a row, but filter on the max (or min or something) on one column you can do this in many different ways.

One way is to find the max app version rows for each user in a derived table that you join with to filter the rows returned, another option is to use a correlated `not exists` query that checks that there doesn't exists any row for the same user with a later app version (and the same platform).

The two queries aren't exactly the same as the first doesn't take the platform into account, but if you want that you can just add it to the derived table, group by and join.

```
select t1.* 
from your_table t1
inner join (
  select `user id`, max(`app version`) as max_app_version
  from your_table 
  group by `user id`
) t2 
on t1.`user id` = t2.`user id` 
and t1.`app version` = t2.max_app_version;


select t1.* 
from your_table t1
where not exists (
  select 1 from your_table 
  where `app version` > t1.`app version`
  and `user id` = t1.`user id`
  and platform = t1.platform
);
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7baf1/4)

Comment: The first option doesn't work because that does not grab the other information from the rows. (For example, i have a user with two app versions, one on android and one on ios and it returns the higher app version but not the platform correlated with that version for that user.
However, the second method seems to work and grab the rest of the information from the applicable row. Thanks!

Comment: @helpplz I thought it might be that way (with users with several apps), which was why I included the second version. Happy it worked.