# Select account_id by max Date

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello I have the following table design

```
ID       account_id       score     date
------------------------------------------    
1       500             4               x
2       764             4               x
3       500             6               x
4       500             7               x
5       764             5               x
```

I'm trying to get **all** rows with the latest account_id entry

so my code should return

```
ID       account_id       score     date
------------------------------------------    
4       500             7               x
5       764             5               x
```

I tried the following code but it seems to return the first entry but with the latest date

```
SELECT account_id,score, max(date) from table group by account_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1: If `id` is auto-increment column or max(id) means latest row.

```
select * from
(select * from table_name
order by id desc) temp
group by account_id
```

Case 2: If `date` column decides latest row then replace `id` by `date` in `order clause` and `group clause`.

Answer (score 0):

try it-

```
SELECT distinct a.id,a.account_id,b.score,b.date 
FROM mytable b 
JOIN 
(
SELECT account_id,MAX(id) AS id 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY account_id
) a ON a.account_id=b.account_id
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is just a duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

There you'll find a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT `account_id`,MAX(`date`) AS latest FROM table GROUP BY account_id 
) b
ON a.`date` = b.`latest` AND a.`account_id` = b.`account_id`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Reference :

[Using ORDER BY and GROUP BY together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030787/using-order-by-and-group-by-together)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query it works fine

```
Select a.account_id,a.score,a.date
from authors as a
join
(Select account_id,max(date) as date
from authors
group by account_id) as d
on(d.date=a.date)
```