# How to change row order using order & group in PgAdmin, sql?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by, pgadmin

I would like to re-order rows from two columns in an existing table without creating a new one. I have this script, that works, **table name** test.table:

```
   SELECT value, variety
    FROM test.table
    group by value, variety
    order by value, variety;
```

I have tried `update` and `alter table`, but I can not get it to work e.g:

```
update test.table
SELECT value, variety
FROM test.table
group by value, variety
order by value, variety;
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have a look at [this qustion and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030787/using-order-by-and-group-by-together) for using group by and orde by together.

Comment: my script works, I just do not understand how to apply it to the table. How to  alter it. Do I **have to** create a new one using create table?

Comment: You should then create a "view",  SQL table can not be used to store grouped and ordered data. it is simply ordered in default insertion order.

Comment: Please read [thi page](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) for basic info about creating views in mysql