# group by and order together not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I am running this query

```
 return $this->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'OR' => array(
                        'Chat.sender_id' => $user_id,
                        'Chat.receiver_id' => $user_id
                    )

                ),


                'group' => array('converstation_id'),
                 'order' => array('Chat.id DESC')


            ));
```

But If I add **Group By**  then **order** don't work in this query. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: They can't work together at least from single query. You need to use sub query or multiple query, See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030787/using-order-by-and-group-by-together

Comment: Order can only be applied after Group.  This means the ordering is being applied to the grouped results.

Answer (score -1):

The order should be as followes:

```
'order' = array('Chat.id' => 'DESC')
```

This, as order requests an array where the value is the order direction.
More information on https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html