# How to display last row of a select count instead of first row?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have this table `calls`

```
id | clientid | salespersonid | duration | statusid | last_update
1  | c11      | sp99          | 05:00    | 1        | yyyy
2  | c11      | sp99          | 06:00    | 1        | yyyy
3  | c11      | sp99          | 07:00    | 3        | yyyy
4  | c12      | sp99          | 08:00    | 3        | yyyy
```

I'm performing this query to count the number of calls per client for each salesperson

```
select *,count(wpc.id) as num_of_calls 
                                    from calls wpc
                                    where wpc.salespersonid=?
                                    group by wpc.clientid
                                    order by wpc.last_update desc
```

This returns this result

```
id | clientid | salespersonid | duration | statusid | last_update|num_of_calls
1  | c11      | sp99          | 05:00    | 1        | yyyy       |3
4  | c12      | sp99          | 08:00    | 3        | yyyy       |1
```

The query is fine but I'm not satisfied with the order in which the program counts and displays the rows. It displays the first row of the count. I'm wanting it to display the last row of each count.

So the result should be

```
id | clientid | salespersonid | duration | statusid | last_update|num_of_calls
3  | c11      | sp99          | 07:00    | 3        | yyyy       |3
4  | c12      | sp99          | 08:00    | 3        | yyyy       |1
```

How can I display the last row of each count instead of the first one?

Comment: Would the `limit` clause work for you?

Comment: @7Reeds: Yes as long as it returns the num_of_calls properly yes.

Comment: You can't guarantee either with this kind of query. While it usually works out that the non-aggregated non-grouped fields are the first _encountered by MySQL_; MySQL does not guarantee that at all. Any non-aggregated non-grouped fields should be considered a random choice of the values seen for those fields with the grouped combination of fields.... `SELECT a, b, c FROM t GROUP BY a` does not even guarantee b and c will be from the same row. If you want the last (or first row) of each group, you typically need a subquery that identifies that row, that is then joined against to get that row.

Comment: This query is NOT fine!!!

Comment: @Strawberry: Okay? Mind giving more details? By the way the MAX still will return same rows 1 and 4. The desired result is row 3 and 4.

Comment: @Uueerdo: Thanks for this sound comment. Would you mind showing it to me? I tried with MAX and it does not work.

Comment: That's because you've not studied the accepted answer at the linked question.

Comment: The answer @Strawberry linked covers exactly what you're asking.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b14706/2

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Using ORDER BY and GROUP BY together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030787/using-order-by-and-group-by-together)

Using solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35053900/2397717

```
 SELECT wpc.*, COUNT(wpc.id) AS num_of_calls FROM (SELECT * FROM calls ORDER BY last_update DESC) as wpc GROUP BY wpc.clientid
```

Comment: No this does not work as desired. I just tested it.

Comment: Here's a working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86366/8)

Comment: It still returns row 1 and row 4. It should return row 3 and 4.

Comment: It should work now.