# MySQL issue with descending order

Tags: php, mysql

My query :

```
$strSQL = "Select customers.*, count(ordersbase.OrderID) As Orders, ordersbase.OrderTime
        From customers
        Inner Join ordersbase On customers.ID = ordersbase.CustomerID
        Group By customers.ID
        Order By customers.ID, ordersbase.OrderTime Desc;";
```

Orders table:

[image]

I expected to get the `OrderTime` value as `20181008000000` (highest value in descending order) but it returns the other one:

```
    "0": {
        "Orders": 2,
        "OrderTime": "20181006000000"
    },
```

Comment: it returns one because you are using Group By customers.ID you can use aggregate function.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030787/using-order-by-and-group-by-together

Comment: @Ntwobike, yes both are same.

Comment: @NanheKumar, sir, i am not looking for two result, i just looking for correct value, as it returning the wrong date :( for descending order :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Data is stored in an unordered fashion. Any non-aggregated column (which is not functionally dependent to columns in `Group By`) in the `Select` clause, and also not specified explicitly inside the `GROUP BY` clause, is non-deterministic. You need to use [`Max()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) function to get the latest order time. Do Read: [SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column .... incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc)
- `Order by` is processed after grouping is already done. So, your usage of `Order by` does not work.

Try the following instead:

```
$strSQL = "Select customers.*, 
                  count(ordersbase.OrderID) As Orders, 
                  MAX(ordersbase.OrderTime) 
        From customers
        Inner Join ordersbase On customers.ID = ordersbase.CustomerID
        Group By customers.ID
        Order By customers.ID";
```