# MySQL order by before group by did not work

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

> users

```
user_id | name
1       | John
2       | Jess
```

> user_data (in_out - 1 indicate in, 0 indicate out)

```
id | user_id | in_time              | out_time             | in_out
1  | 1       | 2019-05-14 09:15:32  | 2019-05-14 10:45:32  | 0
2  | 1       | 2019-05-15 10:15:32  | 0000-00-00 00:00:00  | 1
3  | 2       | 2019-05-16 11:15:32  | 2019-05-16 12:15:32  | 0
```

I want to get latest entries of each user, but group by and order by did not work well.

First I tried following way, but this is not give latest records (I want to get record id 2 and 3 from user_data table, but it returns record id 1 and 3)

```
SELECT *, user.user_id as user_key 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN user_data ON user_data.user_id = user.user_id 
GROUP BY user_data.user_id ORDER BY user_data.id DESC
```

Secondly I tried following way, I wrote this query following an answer of stackoverflow, but it did not work.

```
SELECT *, user.user_id as user_key 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN 
( 
SELECT MAX(user_data.id) as max_record_id, user_data.user_id 
FROM user_data 
GROUP BY user_data.user_id 
) u2 ON u2.user_id = user.user_id 
GROUP BY user_data.user_id ORDER BY user_data.id DESC
```

Someone please help me to solve this issue. Thank You

Comment: A GROUP BY clause with no aggregate function (eg: COUNT(), SUM(), MAX()) makes no sense at all. It baffles me that MySQL even allows this. Think about it, why are you grouping if you don't do anything with the groups? [said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030787/using-order-by-and-group-by-together)

Comment: Your second query is almost right, you should just remove the last line `GROUP BY user_data.user_id ORDER BY user_data.id DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a correlated subquery

```
SELECT *, user.user_id as user_key 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN user_data u2 ON u2.user_id = user.user_id 
where u2.id in (select MAX(u3.id) from user_data u3 where u2.user_id=u3.user_id)
ORDER BY u2.id
```